# Regarding the interpretation of Cramers'V and Phi

Tags: categorical-data, association-measure, cramers-v

How should I interpret Cramer's V when I have more than two variables in cross-tabulation table? Does the order of variables matter?

E.G   Gender , Age , Job , Income level

Is Cramer's V the association of these four factors altogether or just the two of them only under a given condition e.g the association between job and income level under the condition that those are female and 20-30 years old?